# Save ggplot object as reactive object in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a linked zoom plot (via `brushOpts`) in Shiny and am following the example posted [here](https://github.com/rstudio/webinars/blob/master/16-Interactive-graphics/10-linked-zooming.R).

In my code, I define a reactive `data.frame` that I use to create (what I think is) a reactive `ggplot()` object which is then sent to `renderPlot`:

```
# Reactive data.table
dat <- reactive({
    fpath <- paste(basepath, input$lab_name, input$experiment, sep = "/") 

    # some files aren't read - based on the words dataset or eff in the file name
    file_no_suffix <- dir(fpath, full.names = T)[-grep("dataset|eff", dir(ll, full.names = T))]

    # readExpData used fread to read csv file and format it a certain way
    dt <- readExpData(file_no_suffix)

    return(dt)
  }

)

# Reactive ggplot object
plt <- reactive({ggplot(dat())})

# Drop down menu for x-axis of plot
output$dynchoices1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "mainplot_x", label = "Select X-axis", choices = colnames(dat()))
  })

# Drop down menu for y-axis of plot
output$dynchoices2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "mainplot_y", label = "Select Variable to Plot", choices = colnames(dat()))
  })

# Actual plot to display
output$mainplot <- renderPlot({
    mainplt <- plt + geom_point(aes_string(x = input$mainplot_x, y = input$mainplot_y),
                                color = "#003366")
return(mainplt)
})
```

The above code returns errors for both `fread` and `ggplot` in Rstudio console:

```
Warning: Error in fread: 'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, 
a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself
    102: fread
    101: readClabData [C:/Users/LT11231/Documents/R Directory/readExpData.R#52]
    100: <reactive:dat> [#10]
    ... rest truncated for brevity

Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator
Stack trace (innermost first):
    102: renderPlot [#25]
     92: <reactive:plotObj>
     81: plotOb
    ... rest truncated for brevity
```

Despir the error, it is clear that `dat()` is being created since `colnames(dat() )` is being used to generate `choices` for two `selectInput` call that determine the x and y axes of the plot - I can see those in the App. The plot itself is missing:

[image]

If I don't define `plt` separately and write the entire expression as

```
output$mainplot <- renderPlot(ggplot(dat() + 
                                     aes_string(x = input$mainplot_x, y = input$mainplot_y)) + 
                              geom_point()
```

it works okay (still get the warnings for `fread` though).

I don't want to go this way since I expect to have several plots and I don't want to re-write this code for each such instance.

Comment: For the ggplot error, you have to use `plt()` in your `output$mainplot` call since you've made it a reactive object.

Comment: Also added, `environment = environment()` to `ggplot` - works now. Issues with a linked zoom plot now but should be easier now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help :)